# How to make this animation smoother? / Trouble with rotation in pose mode

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

So I have this skateboarding animation I'm trying to make and right nows its really choppy :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScIIR_mVqUE

Im trying to recreate this trick: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySGpAXXeL1g

I rigged the board so one bone tilts the board itself and the root bone controls the entire thing for moevement. When I was rotating the board during the trick I was having a really hard time even rotating it as when I did get the final rotation the Y-value would be much higher then the rest in order for it to flip all the way causing it to just spin super fast.

How would I go about making this smoother? I feel like there's something I'm missing or could do better.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating things a tad.

If you examine the key poses of the sample animation, its basically:

1: Jump

2: Before landing; board flips on local z 180 degrees.

3: Before landing; board flips on  local x/y (whichever is the "roll axis") 360 degrees.

4: Land

So if you just break each part into its constituent elements, basically just:

Frame 0 - Key location  at beginning, rotation.

Frame end: Key location at end, rotate board on 180/360 degrees on relevant axes, key rotation.

middle frame: Key board location to be at "Jump height".

Then you can just tweak curves after that to get the timing right.

I'm no animator, but this is what I got after fiddling for like 7 minutes.

[image]

[image]

Obviously this is highly imperfect, but I just made this example to make sure it wasn't gimbal lock or something.

Comment: Thank you for the response, you think its better to do first frame, end frame, then middle rather then going frame by frame until the end?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, that is standard practice. Get the key poses > Set in between frames > Tweak curves to refine timing.